# border-radius causes solid border to thin out

Tags: html, css

I have a rectangular container with a border radius of 30px. This is to make it have semi circles on the sides instead of flat lines. Unfortunately - this has resulted in the border to thin out as it gets closer to the top or bottom, thinning out to nothing as it reaches the top and bottom.

Any ideas as to what I could do?

```css
#TRLPipe {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 60px;
  align-content: stretch;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
  border-left: 5px solid #e4dfec;
  border-right: 5px solid #4f0072;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="TRLPipe">
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL1">
    TRL 1
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL2">
    TRL 2
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL3">
    TRL 3
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL4">
    TRL 4
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL5">
    TRL 5
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL6">
    TRL 6
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL7">
    TRL 7
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL8">
    TRL 8
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL9">
    TRL 9
  </div>
</div>
```

[I need the borders to match up all around](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNLo6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps switching to `box-shadow` with `inset` instead of border radius might work:

```
#TRLPipe {
  ...
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px orange, 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  ...
}
```

```css
#TRLPipe {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 60px;
  align-content: stretch;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px orange, 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
}

.TRLButton {
  border-top: 3px solid red;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="TRLPipe">
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL1">
    TRL 1
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL2">
    TRL 2
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL3">
    TRL 3
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL4">
    TRL 4
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL5">
    TRL 5
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL6">
    TRL 6
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL7">
    TRL 7
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL8">
    TRL 8
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL9">
    TRL 9
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Toby. This seems to work well. Is there a way to set the left side to one color and the right side to another?

Comment: Not like you can with `border-radius`. You can overlay two elements and position absolutely to show the left side of one and the right side of another, but the code for that is a bit more extensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `::before` and `::after` elements for the two sides, and hide the access border using the `.TRLButton` elements:

```css
#TRLPipe {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  align-content: stretch;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

#TRLPipe::before, #TRLPipe::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  background: white;
  content: '';
}

#TRLPipe::before {
  left: -1px;
  border-color: #e4dfec;
}

#TRLPipe::after {
  right: -1px;
  border-color: #4f0072;
}

.TRLButton {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0;
  border-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="TRLPipe">
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL1">
    TRL 1
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL2">
    TRL 2
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL3">
    TRL 3
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL4">
    TRL 4
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL5">
    TRL 5
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL6">
    TRL 6
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL7">
    TRL 7
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL8">
    TRL 8
  </div>
  <div class="TRLButton" id="TRL9">
    TRL 9
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. It's not perfect, however. Change the background color of `#TRLButton`, and you'll see the leaks.

Comment: When adding your TRLButton CSS to my own I noticed! However, it doesn't show through even with :hover colour changes with animations. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: btw - you can actually remove `#TRLPipe`'s background. It's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the end caps out of new child elements like this:

```
<div class="container" id="TRLPipe">
  <div class="TRLCap" id="leftCap"></div>
  ...
  <div class="TRLCap" id="rightCap"></div>
</div>
```

Then all the caps and buttons are sibling elements within one flex container.  At this point you have minute control over the style of the borders of these siblings.

The container needs no border, just border-radius and shadow:

```
#TRLPipe {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

The buttons and caps have defaults:

```
.TRLButton, .TRLCap {
  flex:1 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #808080; // default color
  border-bottom: 5px solid #808080; // default color
  font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.TRLCap {
  flex:0 0 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

The left cap has the light purple with no border or radius on the right:

```
#leftCap {
  border: 5px solid #e4dfec;
  border-top-right-radius:0;
  border-bottom-right-radius:0;
  border-right:none;
}
```

The right cap has the dark purple with no border or radius on the left:

```
#rightCap {
  border: 5px solid #4f0072;
  border-top-left-radius:0;
  border-bottom-left-radius:0;
  border-left:none;
}
```

And the individual buttons have top and bottom border colors:

```
#TRL1 {
  border-top: 5px solid #e4dfec;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #e4dfec;
}
...
#TRL9 {
  border-top: 5px solid #4f0072;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #4f0072;
}
```

See my JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/kopanoj/edit?html,css,output